# Check if anchor opens in popup or new window

Tags: jquery, events, popup, anchor

As part of a jQuery plugin I am writing I want to add a class to anchor tags on a page that link to another page. Here's what I've got so far:

```
$('a').each(function(){
         url = $(this).attr("href");//grab the url

        if(url != undefined && url.length > 0){             
            if(url.slice(0, 1) != "#"){//We don't want ones that are links within the same page
                //We also dont want ones that are associted with popups
                rel_check = $(this).attr("rel");
                if (!rel_check) {                       
                    //has it got any events attached to it?
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

So I filter out any links within the same page. I check if any of the links have a rel attribute - I guess this will eliminate some anchors associated with popups (I know fancybox, greybox and lightbox use rel tags, but not always...). So here's where I get stuck. An anchor may open in a popup but not have a rel attribute. How do I check for this? I thought checking for any events attached to an element might do the trick but I can't quite seem to get it work work. Any ideas?

Comment: Did the trick nicely, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll be better off checking `target` attribute. For example a link with `target="_blank"` will open in a new tab.

However, if the link is managed by javascript, you won't be able to decide if it will open a new tab/page or not. So you might want to eliminate all links which has a click handler:

```
var eventObj = $(this).data('events');
if (!eventObj || !eventObj.click) {
  // this element doesn't have a click handler.
}
```